# Generalising results on superfluid Kubo formulas

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, statistical-physics, fluid-dynamics

In a [2014 article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FJHEP04%282014%29186) by Chapman, Hoyos and Oz, the authors study non-equilibrium fluid dynamics and describe a method for deriving [Kubo formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubo_formula) for thermal transport coefficients of superfluids (the method relies on the equilibrium partition function).

Near the end of the article, a few possible generalisations of their results are mentioned and I was wondering what work had been done on these in the meantime.  These include Kubo formulas for first order non-dissipative transport coefficients of anomalous fluids, Kubo formulas for relativistic Rindler hydrodynamics at second order, and Kubo formulas for superfluids with multiple broken charges.

Another generalisation would be for superfluids with multiple unbroken non-abelian charges rather than abelian charges.

Comment: since there is an accepted answer pre-bounty, you might want to indicate more precisely what is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but Shukla and Kovtun have provided all Kubo formulas for non-dissipative transport coefficients [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FJHEP10%282018%29007)